# Oracle SQL: How to drop columns that start with certain characters?

Tags: database, oracle, plsql

Folks, I have a table with 300+ columns, out of which ~150 columns, that start with "OP_..." is not needed.

Would it be possible to write a query like,

```
Select * from TableA
drop columns start with OP_
```

in Oracle SQL/PL/SQL? Your comments are appreciated..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try to run as one statement. Execute this select to generate the alter table statement, then execute that:

```
select to_clob('alter tableA drop (') || to_clob(listagg(column_name,',') ||')')
from user_tab_columns 
where table_name = 'TABLEA'
and column_name like '%OP_%'
```

If you want to do as individual statements, then you can execute a pl/sql block like this:

```
begin
  for rec in (select 'alter tableA drop (' || column_name ||')' drop_stmt
              from user_tab_columns
              where table_name = 'TABLEA'
              and column_name like '%OP_%') LOOP
     execute immediate  rec.drop_stmt
   END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: Thanks for your response @OldProgrammer. Your solution yields, "alter tableA drop ()" but this helped me to conceive a different idea: -- is this a correct approach: to create a temp table , select * into it, and then alter temptable drop ()? I just need to fine tune the sql you have provided so it works for me

Comment: no need to create a temp table.  Just tweak the constraints if I got them wrong

Comment: It worked. Is it possible to store the output of the SQL that generates the alter table statement in a string and executing that variable within PL/SQL?